# calling my python code to display execution result

Tags: python

I am having a problem with displaying the result of my code despite following the many answers provided here.

How do I get the result of running a python script I wrote. It takes a directory as input from command line and should return the index files of executing bwa index script but I am not getting any output.Here is my code:

```
def bwaIndex(argv):
    input_dir = sys.argv[1]
    script = 'bwa index'
    for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_dir,"*.fasta")):
        if infile.endswith('*.fasta'):
            subprocess.call(["script, infile"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bwaIndex(sys.argv)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or if I am even right to an extent.

Comment: Given your argument to `subprocess.call` is a single string with a comma in it, I'm guessing that's at least part of the problem, but perhaps that was just a transcription error?  If you have a file called `bwa index` with the space in the name your argument to `call` could be `[script, infile]` without quotes, but I bet you really want `bwa` and `index` to be different arguments, right?  So you invoke `bwa` and pass it the first argument as `index`?

Comment: To index the fasta file, I need to invoke the command bwa index because index alone will not work since it is part of bwa. That was why I passed it as script in my code. Not sure if I am right but I tried earlier without the quotes in [script, infile] but it did not work. I am actually getting no result at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: I went through that earlier. it seem not to answer my question Jarrod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `subprocess.call` is a list of arguments, it does not do any wordsplitting or pass it to the shell (unless you specify `shell=True` but that way is error prone and generally not recommended).  So each "word" or each thing you want to have treated as a separate argument should be its own item in the list.  In this case, you want 3 arguments, `bwa` (the executable to run), `index` (the command to have `bwa` run) and the file to operate on, which is stored in `infile`.  So you probably want to do something like the following:

```
def bwaIndex(input_dir):
    for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_dir, "*.fasta")):
        subprocess.call(['bwa', 'index', infile])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bwaIndex(sys.argv[1])
```

Note that I changed the argument to `bwaIndex` to be the directory instead of an unused reference to `sys.argv` and also since the `glob` will only expand to things that end in `fasta` I dropped that inner check.  Then I made your arguments to `subprocess.call` be the tokens you want to execute.

Comment: Thank you Eric for the clear explanation. I understand how subprocess works now and yes that sys.argv was really unused. It works now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using subprocess.call() you can use subprocess.Popen()

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['program', 'arg1'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
print output
```

see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) more info about subprocess